# Generating random values in Swift between two integer values

Tags: swift, random

I'm trying to generate random values between two integers. I've tried this, which starts from 0,

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
println(randomNumber)
```

But I need a value between 10 and 50.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

try this

```
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(40) + 10
println(randomNumber)
```

in general form

```
let lower : UInt32 = 10
let upper : UInt32 = 50
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower
println(randomNumber)
```

Comment: add one to `upper - lower` in order to allow 50 as possible result here (since `arc4random_uniform(40)` will return integers in the range 0 -to- 39)

Comment: @ackStOverflow that depends OP want `1..50` or `1...50`

Answer (score 49):

This is an option for Swift 4.2 and above using the `random()` method, which makes it easy!

```
let randomInt = Int.random(in: 10...50)
```

The range can be a closed (`a...b`) or half open (`a..<b`) range.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a reusable function with simple parameters:

```
func generateRandomNumber(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    let randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max) - UInt32(min)) + UInt32(min))
    return randomNum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

more simple way of random number generator

```
func random(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1))) + min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate exclusively between 2 integers, you can use

```
func random(_ x: UInt32, _ y: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    Bool.random() ? x : y 
}
```

But if you want to generate between 2 integers range, you can use

```
func random(_ lower: UInt32, _ upper: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    Int.random(in: lower...upper)
}
```